# Why error object does not have status code and statusMessage?

Tags: angular, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

Here is the scenario:

The service class is generated from the swagger editor and is imported in my Angular project.

There are different endpoints and for the sake of this question, I am posting below one of the main endpoints.

```
public getCompanies(pageNumber: string, pageSize: string, sortOrder: string, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<Array<Company>>;
public getCompanies(pageNumber: string, pageSize: string, sortOrder: string, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<Company>>>;
public getCompanies(pageNumber: string, pageSize: string, sortOrder: string, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean): Observable<HttpEvent<Array<Company>>>;
public getCompanies(pageNumber: string, pageSize: string, sortOrder: string, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false ): Observable<any> {
    if (pageNumber === null || pageNumber === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter pageNumber was null or undefined when calling getCompanies.');
    }
    if (pageSize === null || pageSize === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter pageSize was null or undefined when calling getCompanies.');
    }
    if (sortOrder === null || sortOrder === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter sortOrder was null or undefined when calling getCompanies.');
    }

    let queryParameters = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomHttpUrlEncodingCodec()});
    if (pageNumber !== undefined) {
        queryParameters = queryParameters.set('pageNumber', <any>pageNumber);
    }
    if (pageSize !== undefined) {
        queryParameters = queryParameters.set('pageSize', <any>pageSize);
    }
    if (sortOrder !== undefined) {
        queryParameters = queryParameters.set('sortOrder', <any>sortOrder);
    }

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    // authentication (oauth) required
    if (this.configuration.accessToken) {
        let accessToken = typeof this.configuration.accessToken === 'function'
            ? this.configuration.accessToken()
            : this.configuration.accessToken;
        headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    }

    // to determine the Accept header
    let httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
        'application/json'
    ];
    let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected != undefined) {
        headers = headers.set("Accept", httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }

    // to determine the Content-Type header
    let consumes: string[] = [
        '*/*'
    ];

    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Company>>(`${this.basePath}/companies`,
        {
            params: queryParameters,
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: headers,
            observe: observe,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
}
```

Kindly note that the above code is auto-generated and cannot be modified. The above service is subscribed like below,

```
this._myservice.getCompanies( page, size, sortOrder ).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log("Success");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Error: " + error.status);
  }
);
```

Here just for the testing purpose, I am using the console to see the status messages. I have tested one case where the server returns `401 Unauthorised`. The error.status always contains 0.

In browser network window I see that the error code is 401 but in angular it always has status code 0 and statusText "Unknown Error". Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that ErrorResponse object doesn't have "status" property (at least when generating code with swagger code-gen 2.3.1). Did you try accessing error.code or error.message?